# Moving mouse to quickly doesn't trigger mouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following html:

```
<div class="guide-block" id="energy_guide">
    <div class="guide-block-inner">
        <div class="guide-block-head">
            <a class="guide-block-link" href="#">
                <h3 class="guide-block-title">Guides</h3>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="guide-block-image">
            <div class="guide-block-image-inner" id="energy_guide">
                <img src="images/Energy-Saving-Bulb-01.png" alt="Guide">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="guide-block-more">
            <ul class="guide-block-list us-list" id="energy_guide">
                <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Guides</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the following js:

```
$( "#energy_guide" ).mouseenter(function() 
{
    $(".guide-block-image #energy_guide")
    .fadeOut("fast", function() 
    {
        $(".featured_news .guide-block-inner .guide-block-more #energy_guide")
         .fadeIn("fast");
    });
});

$( "#energy_guide" ).mouseleave(function() 
{
    $(".featured_news .guide-block-inner .guide-block-more #energy_guide")
    .fadeOut("fast", function () 
    {
        $(".guide-block-image #energy_guide")
         .fadeIn("fast");
    });

});
```

The list is hidden by default in the css and what i want to achieve is to replace the image with the list while hovering the mouse over the whole guide-block div. Everything is fine and dandy until you move your mouse too fast, the mouseleave function not being triggered for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Just a first idea that hit me was that actually your events are totally fine, rather the way jQuery constructs *Animations* and builds them in the queue.

a probable fix would be to `.stop()` your subsequent animations (*anim. buildups*) so an overall code could look like:

```
$( "#energy_guide" ).hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().fadeToggle();
});
```

(Without seeing a demo of your code with CSS it's a bit hard to guess but here you go)

The way you use your selectors is wrong:

```
.featured_news .guide-block-inner .guide-block-more #energy_guide
```

jQuery will select only `#energy_guide` and taking in considerations that it's the only ID in your document (as it should be) there's no need to use parent *Class* selectors.